# How are JSON Web Token validators tested?

Tags: json

JSON Web Tokens (JWTs) are an open, industry [standard](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7519) method for representing claims securely between two parties. There are [numerous  implementations](https://jwt.io/) for JWT verification but it looks like each author is testing his implementation on his own. It would be great if there was a tool or fuzzer to verify a given implementation is compliant to the standard and is secure. A starting point could be the [RFC 7520](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7520) document that describes fuzz vectors and examples for fuzz testing.

Is there such a tool already?

Or people are testing JWT in the other way?